# Using a Shell Script to determine the connected time

Tags: bash, shell, date

I've looked around the interwebs, including StackOverflow and only found one answer to the same question I am asking (Gotta love homework). However, the asker did not provide any code examples so answer to his question weren't helpful to me.

That being said, I've got a script that requires me to use the date and who commands to determine the length of time in hours and minutes that a user has been connected to their terminal.

This is what I have - which doesn't work properly mathematically.

```
loginHour=$(echo $(who am i) | cut -d' ' -f5 | cut -d: -f1)
loginMin=$(echo $(who am i)  | cut -d' ' -f5 | cut -d: -f2)

currentHour=$(echo $(date) | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d: -f1)
currentMinute=$(echo $(date) | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d: -f2)

echo -n $(expr $currentHour - $loginHour) hour\(s\);echo $(expr $currentMinute - $loginMin) minute\(s\)
```

To answer some questions below:
I am trying to determine how long a user has been connected (using who or using who am i) and date (current time). The scenario is that this doesn't go over 24 hours. So, say I log in at 5:00PM (17:00) and I log out at 7:30PM (19:30) - I need to write a script to compute the time that I was logged in.

Comment: Please could you state (a little more clearly) what you're trying to achieve and where you're having problems achieving it?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time computing time programmaticaly in a bash script, ie different days per month, leap seconds.

Comment: what's the output your getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of what you need is the GNU date command

```
a="19:30"
$ date -d "$a"  +%s
1364520600
```

The number is epoch seconds (seconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970).  In UNIX and Linux, date arithmetic is usually done with epoch seconds

So it is now 19:30; login time is  17:00.

```
a="19:30"
b="17:00"
elapsed= $(( `date -d $a +%s` - `date -d $b +%s`))
```

So, elapsed time was 9000 seconds.  How do you convert 9000 seconds to hours?  Divide by 3600 (seconds in an hour).

```
hr=$(( $elapsed / 3600 ))
min=$(( ($elapsed % 3600) /60  ))
```

This is probably the reason for your assignment - date/time arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I was able to tweak the code using your sample and provide hours and minutes for connected time, using an if to determine if it were necessary to print hours (ex: hrs == 0 only print minutes)